# Divide a number of div in blocks

Tags: jquery

that i need to have converted into

```
<div id="WhateverHolder">

<div class="block">
<div class="item first"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item last"></div>
</div>

<div class="block">
<div class="item first"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item last"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

I have looked for a plugin that can do this but to no avail what is the easiest way to do  this in jQuery

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take your time and learn how SO works. For example in the boxes next to the input field or  on http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help is described how to format code properly (so that you can avoid "custom escaping" with `[]` ;) )

Comment: Should it only work for 8 elements or should it scale?

Comment: Is the content in `#WhateverHolder` always so that it can be divided evenly into blocks? What if only 7 `div` s are contained? Should the last block contain e.g. 3 `div` s then? Or do you always want to create two blocks? You have to explain the pattern that your division is based on!

Comment: Do you really need to add the "first" and "last" classes? You can probably use the :first and :last selectors in jquery and css to accomplish the same objective

Comment: thanks for the comments I will read up on the site.

This should  scale so if there are 9 then one block only has i in them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the jQuery function `.slice(...)`:

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
var items = $("#WhateverHolder > div.item");

var blockCount = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i+= blockCount) {
    var slice = items.slice(i,i + blockCount);      

    slice.first().addClass('first');
    slice.last().addClass('last');

    slice.wrapAll("<div class=\"block\"></div>");
}
```

It will make a new block on the nine'th element. And otherwise make it exactly as you want with first and last classes.

Comment: It's easier to with :lt and :gt selectors.

Comment: @Dorian Also if it should scale to X elements?

Comment: I don't know, but yes, after 2 blocks, it's easier with slice.

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? It works perfect here. Please comment

Comment: Thanks this does the dividing up in blocks with 8 but also with 11 items and does the first and last class as well

Comment: Yes, exactly as your described in your comment to your own question. Did you downvote it? really bad style when my answer actually works

Comment: No i did not downvote it so far this is the only one that works was waiting for someone to comment on this downvote as well

Comment: Thanks, I apologies then :) Good luck with your site

Answer (score 0):

You can use [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (you can improve this) :

```
place = $('#WhateverHolder')
place.find('div:lt(4)').wrapAll('<div class="block" />')
place.find('div:gt(4)').wrapAll('<div class="block" />')
place.find('.block').each(function (i, e) {
  e = $(e)
  e.find('div:first').addClass('first')
  e.find('div:last').addClass('last')
});
```

**Edit** : **It Works** (with your example) ! (It's easy to made it more flexible (with .each() and .slice())

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuerys .slice()` and `.wrapAll()` method to accomplish that task.

```
$(function(){
   var $set = $('.item');

   for(var i = 0, len = $set.length; i < len; i+=4){
      $set.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="block"/>');
   }
});​
```

This would wrap each `four` **div.item** elements into `one` **div.block**.

See: [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Example: http://jsbin.com/ahuvu3/edit

Answer (score -1):

```
var MAX_CHILDREN_PER_BLOCK = 4;
var parent = $('#WhateverHolder');
var currentBlock;
parent.find('.item').each(function() {
   if (!currentBlock) {
       currentBlock = $('<div class="block"></div>');
       currentBlock.appendTo(parent);
   }
   $(this).appendTo(currentBlock);
   if (currentBlock.children().size() == MAX_CHILDREN_PER_BLOCK) {
       currentBlock = null;
   }
});
parent.find('.block').each(function() {
   $(this).find('.item:first').addClass('first');
   $(this).find('.item:last').addClass('last');
});
```

Edit: Tested and solved bug explained in the comments

Comment: Also tested this one, the block part works but when i try with a children per block of 3 , on the last block ( the one that only has 2 doesn't have the item first and item last )

Comment: You are right, I have solved that problem and tested it in case you want to make use of the code

Answer (score -2):

Here're my 2 cents:

```
 var listItemsPerList = 10;
 var listItems = $("#WhateverHolder > div").length;

 for (var i = 0; i < Math.round(listItems / listItemsPerList); i++) {
     var startingItem = i * listItemsPerList;
     var endingItem = (i + 1) * listItemsPerList;
     if (endingItem > listItems) { endingItem = listItems };
     $("#WhateverHolder > div").slice(startingItem, endingItem).wrapAll("<div class="block"></div>");
 }

 $("#WhateverHolder").replaceWith($("#WhateverHolder").children());
```

Comment: this one doesn't seem to work with if i do 4 then it puts the first 4 in a block then 3 normal ones and then it put the last one in a block again

Comment: Aham, I guess you don't like to adjust and debug things? 
Just pure copy/paste? 
Nevermind...